# android popupmenu trigger scrolling of listview

Tags: android, popupmenu

When I open popupmenu from listview item it sometimes triggers an unnecessary (small) scrolling of listview.

Can anybody explain why? Can I avoid it?

Comment: The Android Support Library bug tracker for this issue: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=135439